# How to understand that convert half-precision pointer to unsigned long long pointer and relevant memory alignment?

Tags: c++, pointers, cuda

I am not familiar with the problems about memory alignment and pointer conversion. I am learning from the Nvidia official sample code as the following.

```
  half *A = NULL;
  half *B = NULL;
  float *C = NULL;
  float *D = NULL;

  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&A),
                             sizeof(half) * M_GLOBAL * K_GLOBAL));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&B),
                             sizeof(half) * N_GLOBAL * K_GLOBAL));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&C),
                             sizeof(float) * M_GLOBAL * N_GLOBAL));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&D),
                             sizeof(float) * M_GLOBAL * N_GLOBAL));

  assert(((unsigned long long)A) % 128 == 0);
  assert(((unsigned long long)B) % 128 == 0);
  assert(((unsigned long long)C) % 128 == 0);
  assert(((unsigned long long)D) % 128 == 0);
```

I have three questions toward to this.

1. I know the difference between pointer type conversion and numerical type conversion. With respect to pointer type conversion, we just change the way to understand that pointer. But how should I understand the conversion from `half*` to `unsigned long long*`?
2. I think the memory address should keep unchanged during this conversion. Why do we need to convert to `unsigned long long*` first and then check if the memory is aligned with 128?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how should I understand the conversion from `half*` to `unsigned long long*`?

There is no conversion to `unsigned long long *` in the code you show. There is a conversion to `unsigned long long`.

The purpose of the conversion is to convert the address stored in one of `A`, `B`, `C`, or `D` to an integer so that its bits may be examined. The C standard does not define the result of converting a pointer to an integer type except for some basic properties, but the conversion is “intended to be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment” (C 2018 footnote 69). In the compiler Nvidia uses, the conversion presumably produces the address as normally used by the processor architecture. Then using `% 128 == 0` tests whether the address is aligned to a multiple of 128 bytes.

> Why do we need to convert to `unsigned long long*` first and then check if the memory is aligned with 128?

The `%` operator will not accept a pointer operand, so the operand must be converted to an integer type, `unsigned long long`, not `unsigned long long *`.

Comment: Thank you first. One more question please. I do not know in what situation there will be non consistent with the addressing structure?

Comment: @Sean: Many modern machines simply use a sequence of bits to denote an address. Some machines use some bits to denote a base of some kind and other bits to denote an offset. In those machines, an address is not a simple integer. Some machines have instructions only for words of, say, 32 bits, and a C implementation can present a view of byte addressing only by adding its own bits to the machine address. The C standard committee did not want to specify rules for all these possibilities, so they left it to implementations to figure out the conversion.

Comment: @Sean: Theoretically, in an architecture where addresses are simply sequences of bits with no complicated structure, a C implementation could convert an address to an integer by multiplying by 3 modulo 2^64 (and perform the reverse conversion by multiplying by the multiplicative inverse). This would satisfy the technical requirements of the standard, but it would not be “consistent” with the addressing structure. The idea of consistency to say that, if somebody knows the addressing mechanisms of the machine, and they convert a pointer to an integer, the result they get should make sense.